# Facebook share ui callback not called when cancel button is pressed

Tags: javascript, facebook, user-interface, share

I am using the Facebook ui to share an url. I'm trying to raise an event when it is successfully shared and when it's not. The response is always empty, so I can not tell if it has been shared or not.

This is my callback function:

```
            function(response) {
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(response.post_id));
                 if (response && response.post_id) {
                //console.log('Posting completed.');
                var Sharesuccess = "Share_Sucess";

                } else {
                //console.log('Error while posting.');
                var NotShared = "Not_Shared";
                }
             }
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#response

Comment: The users need to be logged in for the repsonse to anything but empty: **Response Data** _Only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and has granted publish_actions. If present, this is the ID of the published Open Graph story_. See:[link]https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#response